# NuGet Package for IBotContext.GetAccessToken()?

Tags: c#, .net, bots, botframework, nuget-package

I am trying to create an Authentication service for my bot I built using the Bot Framework. At one point in my code I try to do the following:

```
 public async Task defaultMessage(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
 {
     var token = await context.GetAccessToken();

     // Other code...

 }
```

but a reference for the method GetAccessToken() can't be found? I am going by the [AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot) example. I think I missed installing a Nuget package? But I haven't been able to find out which one I need from searching online. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have that extension method available, you have to install the [AuthBot](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AuthBot) Nuget package to your solution and add the following using to your the class where you want to use it:

```
using AuthBot
```

The extension method is defined in [ContextExtensions](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot/blob/master/AuthBot/ContextExtensions.cs) class.